# How to define compile-time -D macros (Apache 2.2)?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-construction, apache2, libtool

While compiling Apache source, I've been able to define one macro just fine:

```
# export CFLAGS=" -DSINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT"   // OR even:
# export CFLAGS=" -DSINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT=1"
```

... works like a charm, **however** every time I try to set:

```
# export CFLAGS=" -DDEFAULT_PIDLOG=/var/run/apache/apache.pid"
```

I get this error during `make`:

```
prefork.c: In function ‘prefork_pre_config’:
prefork.c:1340:20: error: expected expression before ‘/’ token
make[4]: *** [prefork.lo] Error 1
```

So I've tried escaping the forward slashes and different quoting techniques of DEFAULT_PIDLOG's value, but it always fails, apparently because of the forward slashes in the value.

Comment: Seems that DEFAULT_PIDLOG is expected to define a constant C string. try with  `export CFLAGS=" -DDEFAULT_PIDLOG=\\\"/var/run/apache/apache.pid\\\""`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that DEFAULT_PIDLOG is expected to define a constant C string. Try with

```
export CFLAGS="-DDEFAULT_PIDLOG=\\\"/var/run/apache/apache.pid\\\""
```

(Thanks @mathk)

Answer (score 0):

`DEFAULT_PIDLOG` is expected to define a constant C string. try with export CFLAGS=" -DDEFAULT_PIDLOG=\\"/var/run/apache/apache.pid\\"

Comment: Is there a quote missing from the end of your export? I haven't tried this yet, but mathk's comment above seems to work (wish it didn't take so long to compile!). If you'd like to include his comment in your answer, I'll mark it correct and get on with the day.

Comment: Followup: Adding another quote at the end of Smirno's export command errors out, so I assume the answer is correct.

Comment: @Jeff: I'd say there definitly is a quotation mark missing. Also how to quote and how to escape might strongly depend on the shell in use. In `bash` for example you'd do: `CFLAGS=-DDEFAULT_PIDLOG=\"/var/run/apache/apache.pid\"`. Same for `ksh`.

Comment: @alk, I tried that exact quoting scheme and it gives me the same error in my question (bash shell). Only the "triple quotes" in mathk's comment above worked.

Comment: @Jeff: So why then did you accept an incorrect answer, as this one here?

Comment: @alk, I don't know that it's incorrect; I didn't try it. My first comment under his answer is pretty clear and should direct anyone to mathk's comment. I assumed Smirno knows his "C" because he obviously examined the source. If you try it and find it's wrong, I'll unmark it and let you answer the question, if you like.